# How to version seeds in Knex?

Tags: database-migration, knex.js

I have a sql file where I write sentences for run in release, this file contains sentences like:

```
-- =======================2019-02-01=======================
UPDATE rating set stars = 3 where id = 6;
UPDATE users SET status = 'A' where last_login >= '2019-01-01';
INSERT INTO....
-- =======================2019-02-15=======================
UPDATE rating set stars = 3 where id = 6;
UPDATE users SET status = 'A' where last_login >= '2019-01-01';
INSERT INTO....
```

I run specifics sentences in each release date, but I believe that is bad practice and its no escalable method.

I'm trying change this method to Knex seeds or migrations. what would be the best practice to do it?

Seeds have a problem because knex executes the seeds every time I write the command `knex seed:run`, and it show some errors.

Comment: Seeds should be used only if you want to insert the same dataset various times to the DB. Migrations are suitable when some initial data is added once during creating schema etc.

Comment: I have used knex migrations similarly to how I described down below in production just fine, you should not run the migrations as part of your deployed app code but you can if you need to minimize administration. Always test things locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knex stores the filenames and signatures of what it has executed so that it does not need to run them again.

https://knexjs.org/#Installation-migrations

Programmatically you can execute migrations like this:

```
knex({..config..}).migrate.latest({
  directory: 'migrations', // where the files are stored
  tableName: 'knex_migrations' // where knex saves its records
});
```

Example migration file

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.raw(`
   UPDATE rating set stars = 3 where id = 6;
   UPDATE users SET status = 'A' where last_login >= '2019-01-01';
   INSERT INTO....
  `)
};
```

The files will be executed alphabetically/sorted, and will not be re-executed against the same database.